# XSD Attributes - are they supposed to appear in order?

Tags: xml, xsd

i have a general question about attributes in XSD Schema.
Do they have to appear in the same order as declared?
  example:

```
<xsd:attribute name="aaa" >
<xsd:attribute name="bbb" >
```

can they appear like this?

```
<shlomi aaa="1" bbb="2" >
```

as they can appear like:

```
<shlomi bbb="2" aaa="1" >
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Attributes are unordered. (that is, although they have an order, being a stream of text, that order is *not significant*).

Therefore, both your XML examples are valid with respect to the XSD fragment you gave.

Comment: And since the attributes in the instance may appear in order, equally, the declarations of attributes in the schema may appear in any order.